# Fixing a broken firefox gmail userscript to work in chrome gmail

Tags: javascript, gmail, reminders, gcal, gtd

This is my first post here so I apologize in advance if I'm not following protocol with this post.

I've been trying to find a replacement solution for this script for years. Hopefully someone here can help the cause. My favorite Gmail Greasemonkey script of all time was called the GTD Tickler. You can see it here ----> http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/7676 (It wasn't a part of the official GTD system)

From any Gmail message, hit one hot key, and it would let you set the time, and automatically add a reminder to your GCAL. The best script EVER, but its broken and won't work in the Google Chrome browser (or Firefox for that matter).

Does anyone know how to fix it?

It looks like the author abandoned his work on it and isn't coming back.

GMail - GTD Tickler for Greasemonkey
Very simple tickler for GMail using GCal( Google Calendar )

Is there something like this that exists that I just can't seem to find? I've seen google apps scripts that are similar but don't let you snooze/tickle by time, only by day. It also didn't create reminders/events.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.....

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to explain as much as possible. 

I use google chrome, and I want to be able to use this script:
http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/7676
in gmail.

The script is a "tickler" that lets you "snooze" an email until a later time, day, or specific date. I believe it uses google calendar too.